# Using .NET's HttpWebRequest to download a multitude of files in a row

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, socketexception

I have an application that needs to download several files in a row in succession (sometimes a few thousand).  However, what ends up happening when several files need to be downloaded is I get an exception with an inner exception of type SocketException and the error code 10048 (WSAEADDRINUSE).  I did some digging and basically it's because the server has run out of sockets (and they are all waiting for 240s or so before they become available again) - not coincidentally it starts happening around the 1024 file range.  I would expect that the HttpWebRequest/ServicePointManager would be reusing my connection, but apparently it is not (and the files are https, so that may be part of it).  I never saw this problem in the C++ code that this was ported from (but that doesn't mean it didn't ever happen - I'd be surprised if it was, though).

I am properly closing the WebRequest object and the HttpWebRequest object has KeepAlive set to true by default.  Next my intent is to fiddle around with ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive().  However, I can't see how more people haven't run into this problem.

Has anyone else run into the problem, and if so, what did you do to get around it?  Currently I have a retry scheme that detects this error and waits it out, but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Here's some basic code to verify what I'm doing (just in case I'm missing closing something):

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
try
{
    using(Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // read the stream
    }
}
finally
{
    webResponse.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What kind of application is this? You mentioned that the server is running out of ports, but then you mentioned HttpWebRequest. Are you running this code in a webservice or ASP.NET page, which is trying to then download multiple files for the same incoming request from the client?

What kind of authentication is the page using? If it is using NTLM authentication, then the connections cannot be shared if the credentials being used are different for each request.

What I would suggest is to group your request per credential. So, for eg, all requests using username "John" would be grouped. You can specify the "ConnectionGroupName" property on the service point, so the system will try to reuse connections for the same credential and server.

If that also doesnt work, you will need to do one or more of the following:

1) Throttle your requests.

2) Increase the wildcard port range.

3) Use the BindIPConnectionCallback on ServicePoint to make it bind to a non-wildcard port (i.e a port in the range 1024-16384)

Answer (score 0):

More digging seems to point to it possibly being due to authentication and the UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing property might alleviate this.  However, I'm not sure that's the best thing, either.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this though - I still get the error when setting this.  It's been a while since I fiddled with this, but I seem to be getting the error today after around 5-6000 attempts.